# ggplot2 loess line fails to be drawn for all groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot some data with unequal n's in each bin. For the categories that are quite unbalanced, ggplot2's `geom_smooth(method="loess")` function fails to draw a line. What can I do to get a line in every box?

I can't provide the full data set, but here's a sample from `dput()`. It only includes data corresponding to the first column from the left in the graph:

```
structure(list(SyllPos = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), Vowel = structure(c(6L, 6L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("a", 
"A", "e", "i", "o", "u"), class = "factor"), F0_min = c(175.4793618612, 
161.9387247949, 156.4967046937, 173.1514145171, 159.8804957163, 
175.2917843952, 172.7116138335, 174.6049809487, 195.8368591846, 
195.4172420312, 182.6852946151, 188.4100959521, 188.983672073, 
214.0355579244, 169.23097112, 152.1439895502, 156.621222189, 
175.8042928291, 171.367861216, 193.7238081091, 179.3106662597, 
182.9049959569, 178.1478311468, 171.9863659221, 185.8157515956, 
196.6284794848, 179.9183082837, 180.7406792084, 165.2450513336, 
152.0289582284, 173.1748795491, 168.4186744926, 188.4070592283, 
149.6196463529, 168.7081562312, 179.1505731882, 151.186575271, 
187.8501100842, 208.5895328686, 167.7112210192, 174.5130946688, 
167.1739428511, 189.0655970555, 198.5328530886, 156.4296130688, 
186.6138701847, 173.8934695337, 159.7378035477, 209.431835937, 
172.915664809, 177.6465488766, 188.7978637368, 172.3481292301, 
178.2089953258, 178.2263785249, 178.2383870226, 174.3579576427, 
201.3184127519, 201.7100790628, 194.3845286637, 174.2388389206, 
177.534, 157.5118957437, 173.408586022, 201.8608904925, 202.1619587211
)), .Names = c("SyllPos", "Vowel", "F0_min"), row.names = c(NA, 
-66L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the output graph and my code:

```
plot <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=as.integer(SyllPos), y=F0_min)) +
    geom_point(shape=1) +
    geom_smooth(method="loess")+
    theme_bw()+
    facet_grid(Vowel ~ SpeakerId)
```

[image: faceted plots with most but not all cells containing a loess line]

Extra kudos to someone who can explain why the 5th cell from the left in the 3rd row and the rightmost cell in the last row have extravagantly large standard errors/wild bumps that do not correspond to any deviant data points.

Comment: It seems like solving this problem would be impossible without seeing at least some of the data. Can you `dput` a sample?

Comment: @camille Thanks for the suggestion, it has been done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the range of x-values is very small (1-3). `geom_smooth()`'s `loess` method uses a parameter `span` that determines the size of the window over which to compute the smoothed curve. With a small range of x-values, `span` by default is correspondingly small  (somewhat less than 1 in this case, though I'm not sure how small precisely). Because the x-axis has only integer values, the `span` parameter can't get sufficient data to compute the smoothed curve within the window. With `span=1`, as in the following call, everything works!

```
plot <- ggplot(mydata , aes(x=as.integer(SyllPos), y=F0_min)) +
    geom_point(shape=1) +
    geom_smooth(method="loess", span = 1)+
    theme_bw()+
    facet_grid(Vowel ~ SpeakerId)
```

[image: almost the same graph as in the question, but with loess lines for all categories, and only computed with F0_min instead of F0_min-min_min on the y-axis]

For the record, I couldn't have done this without having blundered on to this answer (for another question that was summarily down-voted by the community) [Working with span in ggplot2 / geom_smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426822/working-with-span-in-ggplot2-geom-smooth#24431296)